# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter does not work

Tags: windows

```
#include   <windows.h>   

long   __stdcall   callback(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS*   excp)
{
    MessageBox(0, "Error", "error", MB_OK);

    return   EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int   main(int   argc, char*   argv[])
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(callback);
    int *  p;
    free(p);                //to crash
    return   0;
}
```

When I use SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to catch the error,it does not work.My IDE is vs 2013 , x64 system and program. I tried both debug and release ,all failed.

If it was abandoned,how I can get crash dump in the program?

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger the callback, all of the following conditions must be met:

- It must be a debug build, because the invalid free() doesn't cause an exception in a release build.  (It might or might not *indirectly* cause an exception in a larger program, but in the code as posted it does not.)
- You must be running the executable without the debugger, because unhandled exception filters are ignored if a debugger is present.
- You must select the "Ignore" option when presented with the Debug Error window warning you that `p` is being used without being initialized.

I'm not sure what it is that you're actually trying to achieve here, but this is probably not the right way to go about it.